# Python: Specific List Output Inconsistency

Tags: python, list

I believe the output I'm getting is a product of sloppy code somewhere, but I can't seem to get it. What I want my function to do is make a new list of the elements in a list it's being passed, in those elements' Pig-Latin translation. I've got the function working, but it makes all of the new list elements the Pig-Latin translation of only the first element in the list being passed to the function, even though I'm using an index to iterate through the elements of the passed list.

```
def pigLatin(targetlist):
    newlist = () 
    listnewlist = list(newlist)
    index = 0 # gets incremented 
    firstletter = targetlist[index][0] 
    word = targetlist[index][1:] 
    print('Words made into Pig Latin: ')

    while index < len(targetlist):
        listnewlist.append(word + firstletter + 'ay')
        index += 1

    print(listnewlist)
```

which, after user input is `"how now brown cow"`, displays:

```
['owhay', 'owhay', 'owhay', 'owhay']
```

Comment: Your `word = targetlist[index][1:]` is outside the `while` loop, and thus index doesn't get incremented for it.

Comment: Thanks so much! I moved in both word and firstletter and it worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

`word` and `firstletter` are both computed outside of the loop and keep the value of first word of the `targetlist`.

IMHO, you should write :

```
def pigLatin(targetlist):
    newlist = () 
    listnewlist = list(newlist)
    index = 0 # gets incremented 
    print('Words made into Pig Latin: ')

    while index < len(targetlist):
        firstletter = targetlist[index][0] 
        word = targetlist[index][1:] 
        listnewlist.append(word + firstletter + 'ay')
        index += 1

    print(listnewlist)
```